# EC2 API Tools formatting in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

The output of ec2 cli tools on my mac is nice and formatted like so:

```
RESERVATION     r-xxxx      xxxx    cl-xx  
INSTANCE        i-xxxx      ami-xxx                   
TAG     instance        i-xxx      Name    xxxx
etc...
```

On my Ubuntu machine the output is very hard to read. I followed the instructions from the Ubuntu help here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EC2APITools

Does anyone know what I am missing to get better looking output than this?

```
+------------+--------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+--------------------------
------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+------
| instanceId |   imageId    |    instanceState     |                  reason                  | keyName | instanceType |        launchTime        
lId   |   monitoring   |                                           stateReason                                           | architecture | rootDevi
                                           blockDeviceMapping                                                         | virtualizationType |     
+------------+--------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+--------------------------
------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+------
| i-xxxxxx | ami-xxxxxx | code=80 name=stopped | User initiated (2011-07-14 04:14:38 GMT) | somekey   | t1.micro     | 2011-07-14T03:46:43.000Z 
d9529 | state=disabled | code=Client.UserInitiatedShutdown message=Client.UserInitiatedShutdown: User initiated shutdown | i386         | ebs
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a version difference. Compare the output of `ec2-version` on each machine.

Try downloading the EC2 API tools from http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351 (those Ubuntu docs link to a specific version that is probably not the most recent.)